# Dynamic Height of LI within UL

Tags: html, css

So I have a Vertical UL that takes up say 400px height.  Within are 3 (and only 3) li's that I need to scale dynamically to fill the ul.

Here is a fiddle I started.  I know these seems basic, but I am blanking right now.

Thanks for the Help!!

http://jsfiddle.net/NtVQs/

Answer (score 1):

Each `li`-element needs to be one-third of the height, so they completely fill the `ul`-element.

A simple solution is to add

```
height: 33.3%;
```

to the CSS for the `li`-elements. You could also use the absolute known height (400px) and set the height of the `li`-element to one-third of this value:

```
height: 133px;
```

If you want to perfectly fill the height of the `ul`-element you could add this CSS as well:

```
li:first-child {
  height:134px;
}
```

Since 133 + 133 + 134 = 400. (credits for this addition goes to [Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister), see one of the comments on this page)

Answer (score 1):

Giving the height of `33.33%` to all `li`'s solves this problem in an **very simple** way. Check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/NtVQs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but I did this: http://jsfiddle.net/NtVQs/1/

Adding a `height: 33%` to the `LI` tag seemed to do the trick in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah tried that, really looking for something to fill the whole space, has to be a way, thanks though

Comment: You might want to use `33.3%` or even more digits, to 'fix' rounding errors, as 100%/3 != 33%

Comment: And then add `li:first-child {height:33.4%;}` (or more digits) to _really_ fix round-off errors. Edit: Oh, I see Sam already said that.

Comment: That would be even better yes :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/NtVQs/

```
// get UL height
var ​ulHeight​ = $('ul').height();
// set height for the Lis
$('li').height(ulHeight / 3);
$('li').first().height((ulHeight / 3) + ulHeight % 3);
```

I should add that this avoids the problems occuring using a simple css solutions

Comment: and I should add that this adds a complete JavaScript framework for such a simple task :)

Comment: Which is irrelevant in most cases because you need some kind of js lib in every growing project.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a height of 33.3% to the li element you will fill nearly all of the space with 3 equal height boxes. You could then use a pseudo selector to target one of the list elements to fill the final % missing making it 33.4% to cover the missed 0.1%. This won't vertically centre the text but will sort out the filling of the parent UL.

What is this for as it may allow us to suggest another solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PHsNU/

With this you can scale to any number of elements in the list. However, using javascript isn't an ideal solution.